# Missing XML Attributes in Geoserver

Tags: postgis, geoserver, kml, style, fields-attributes

I've imported a number of files that used to be in KML format into geoserver after putting everything into a PostGIS table. Now I would like to use CSS style information that was associated with the original KML files, but  Geoserver says the layers cannot be rendered because they are missing the attributes being called for. Is there any way I can add these attributes to the imported layers?

Comment: Attributes may have dropped when you imported data from KML into PostGIS. What tool did you use for that? Have you checked which attributes you have in your PostGIS tables now?

Comment: I used the ogr2ogr tool for the converter. Would that cause the attributes to be erased?I don't actually have access to  the PostGIS tables right now to check which attributes are there, but from the error messages I'm getting on geoserver, it seems like all of the originally coded attributes are gone.

Comment: It is useless to guess. Have a look at the tables when you can. The structure of KML is not always simple to convert into conventional GIS formats.